# Kubuntu and ui scale

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, 16.10, interface

I'm using kubuntu(latest kernel and os) on a 12" lenovo screen at 1920x1080. Due to small screen size i'm having some hard time to read from distance etc.. What's the best way to scale ui or adjust my settings for more comfortable usage. I don't want my ui messed up because of wrong adjustments like big fonts on small bars etc..

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Changing the DPI. Go to Fonts in the System Settings.

96px is the default, bump it to 144 for 150% "zoom", then relog to apply the setting to everything. Without relogging, it should scale the panel widgets, but you'll need to relog to update the title bars.

Comment: Notably, in later versions, if you do this, it prompts you to change the "Global Scale" under "Display Configuration".